# Migration of a database between different engines

Tags: sql, relational-database, database-migration

I'm looking for a tool that i would be able to use to copy a database stored in one database engine to a different one, eg. from MS SQL Server to PostgreSQL (Only schema, data, indices and FKs). Are there any good free tools?

Comment: I don't think a tool handling all engine migration exists. For postgres you will find a lot of possible tool on their wiki page https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Converting_from_other_Databases_to_PostgreSQL